# How to change name of a tag in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to add/change the name of an input tag within jsx? may be the terms used are wrong as i'm novice in react js. In the table header i need to add radio buttons along with the header text and each header should have different radio button names. I was able to add the radio buttons but facing trouble in giving them a dynamic name (preferably the headers index which is shown in the below code )

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Table.css";
import { Button } from "./Button";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";
class Tables extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      project: {},
      selectedFile: null,
      uploaded: null,
      resp_data: "",
      clicked: 0,
    };
    this.checked = this.checked.bind(this);
  }

  headers = this.props.data[0];
  body = this.props.data[1];
  checked(event) {
    this.setState({ clicked: 1 });
  }

  render() {
    const clicked = this.state.clicked;
    let radio_buttons;
    if (this.props.param === "OneRadio") {
      radio_buttons = <input name="select-radio" type="radio"></input>;
    } else {
      radio_buttons = (
        <>
          **{/* headers contains a list of 10 elemets and each radio button should have different 
           name */}**
          <br />
          <label className="label_label">Radio x</label>
          <input name="select-radio" type="radio"></input>
          <br />
          <label className="label_label ">Radio y</label>
          <input name="select-radio" type="radio"></input>
        </>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="table-div">
        <Table responsive bordered hover>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              {this.headers.map((header, index) => (
                <th key={index}>
                  <label>{header}</label>

                  {/* here radio button for each header is displayed 
                  but for each iteration the radio buttons name should be appended with the index */}
                  
                 {radio_buttons}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.body.map((items, index) => (
              <tr>
                {items.map((subItems, sIndex) => (
                  <>
                    <td>{subItems}</td>
                  </>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
        <Button buttonStyle="btn--secondary" buttonSize="btn--small">
          view data
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tables;
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Current Output :

[image]

It would be a great help if someone could guide me through this. And i would like to know if there is any better way to write this whole code since it is my first time with react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` callback's `index` to set different names for each radio input:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Table.css";
import { Button } from "./Button";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";
class Tables extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      project: {},
      selectedFile: null,
      uploaded: null,
      resp_data: "",
      clicked: 0,
    };
    this.checked = this.checked.bind(this);
  }

  headers = this.props.data[0];
  body = this.props.data[1];
  checked(event) {
    this.setState({ clicked: 1 });
  }

  render() {
    const clicked = this.state.clicked;
    let header_radio_buttons = this.headers.map((header, index) => {
        if (this.props.param === "OneRadio") {
              radio_buttons = <input name="select-radio" type="radio"></input>;
            } else {
              radio_buttons = (
                <>
                  **{/* headers contains a list of 10 elemets and each radio button should have different
                   name */}**
                  <br />
                  <label className="label_label">Radio x</label>
                  <input name={"select-radio" +  (index+1)} type="radio"></input>
                  <br />
                  <label className="label_label ">Radio y</label>
                  <input name={"select-radio" +  (index+1)} type="radio"></input>
                </>
              );
            }
        return(
               <th key={index}>
                 <label>{header}</label>
                 {radio_buttons}
                </th>
        );
    });

    let radio_buttons;


    return (
      <div className="table-div">
        <Table responsive bordered hover>
          <thead>
            <tr>
                 {header_radio_buttons}

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.body.map((items, index) => (
              <tr>
                {items.map((subItems, sIndex) => (
                  <>
                    <td>{subItems}</td>
                  </>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
        <Button buttonStyle="btn--secondary" buttonSize="btn--small">
          view data
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tables;
```

Comment: It worked like charm !! Thanks much for the help Ahmet. Could you please give your comments on the whole code whether it is the proper way to implement or is there any better way?

Comment: You are welcome @liquiddeath. For your code, I would recommend you define headers and body attributes inside render() function instead of defining them on your component. In react, defining new attributes on your class other than the state object is not usually recommended.